# Generic Plugins

Tags: c#, reflection

Hi i write a some plugins

it's look like that

```
public class Person
{
public string Name;
public string Surname;
}

public interface IWork
{
Type GetType {get;} 
}

public interface IWorker<T> : IWork
{
 T GetSingle();
 T[] GetMultiple();
 void DoWork(T object);
}
```

one plugin looks like that

```
public PersonPlugin : IWroker<Person>
{
//implementation of interface
//return typeof(Person);
}
```

And now question, how i can dynamic create a instance for example of IWork ?
How cast as IWork if i have only Type, it's possible ?

i want to do (should be dynamic, for all instance of plugins)

```
IWork<T> iWorkInstalce = (IWork<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PersonPlugin));
```

or

```
IWork iWorkInstalce = (IWork)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PersonPlugin));
IWork<Person> personInstance = (CAST) typeof(IWork<>).MakeGenericType(iWorkInstance.Type);
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that cast? What do you want to do with the result? Can you use C# 4's `dynamic`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast to `IWorker<T>` without specifying what `T` is. If you do that, your first example is valid:

```
IWorker<Person> iWorkInstalce = (IWorker<Person>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PersonPlugin));
```

It is possible to use reflection on the `PersonPlugin` class to find it's implementation of `IWorker<T>`, and then discover what `T` is, but this is only any use as runtime, it won't help you at all in code.

If you know what you expect `T` to be, specify it explicitly. Otherwise, cast to the non-generic `IWork` instead and give it versions of your methods that return `Object`. If you don't know what `T` is at compile-time, having a generic `IWorker<T>` can't really help you here.

If your application needs to know what type your plugin works with at runtime, it can call the `GetType` property.